# When building a jenkins plugin, "hudson.maven package does not exist" message appears. Why?

Tags: maven-2, jenkins

I'm building a Jenkins plugin. It's a migration from a Hudson plugin, to Jenkins plugin.

I've done things according to the tutorial provided at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial . The plugin uses `MavenBuild` class that is inside hudson.maven package. The problem is that when I run `mvn package` or `mvn install` maven throws a Build Failure with the message

> package hudson.maven does not exist.

Somehow build works inside Eclipse. Eclipse doesn't throw any compilation issue. I don't know where to look for solving this issue.

Does someone know where to solve this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your pom file does include maven-plugin
`<build>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</build>`

That's where hudson.maven is.
FYI: this provides the classes for the Maven build jobs, in addition to the free-style build jobs when you create a new build job in the UI.

Comment: I'm not working with this anymore, neither I have the code to try it out. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I placed it under <dependencies> under <project> but it doesnt slove my problem